# Create (and set value for) a new global option using base R?

Tags: r

Global options can be see with `options()`, or to just show the names `names(options())`

I can see a way to make new options of your choosing [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GlobalOptions/vignettes/GlobalOptions.html)

Is there a way to set a new global option so that it appears in the list generated with `options()` but *without* using an external library (i.e. just using base R)?

#### Note

I already know how to set a value for an option (e.g. `options(max.print=200)`), what I am specifically trying to do is create a new option altogether

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm not sure. Can you provide a code example and I'll give it a try?

Comment: No, I don't think it will work. What kind of option would you like to create?

Comment: @NelsonGon I think I know what you were getting at, which was my first line of thought. As in, you can assign the output of `options()` and then edit the list to add a new option. But I don't know how to make the new option be the global options after it's edited.

Comment: Is this what you need? `options(test=2)` but then you'd need to have defined your new "method" say a printing method somewhere. It is stated that R(base) will only use what it knows. If you then call `options("test")` you have a new option but whether it will work is questionable. This will also appear under `options()`.

Comment: @NelsonGon that works perfectly, since `options()$test` returns the value set. You can make it the answer if you prefer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of `options` available via `?options` or `help(options)`, one can set a new option by specifying a name as a character and it's value. This is done using the ellipsis(`...`) argument(dots).

**Note** however, that the same documentation states that

> any options can be defined, using name = value. However, only the ones below are used in base R.
>
> Options can also be passed by giving a single unnamed argument which is a named list.

Therefore, we can create a new option say "my_print" as follows:

`options(my_print=10)`

We can then see that it is now under the list of available options:

```
options()$my_print
[1] 10
```

**Note**:

> It is stated that R(base) will only use what it knows. If you then call options("my_print") you have a new option but whether it will work is questionable. This will also appear under options().

The list of options used by base R can be got by simply calling `options()` if you have not previously defined a new option. They are also available under the details section of the docs.